# Easy Chair Long Screw needs to be tight

Tags: screws, furniture, wooden-furniture

I have an easy arm chair that I bought from Ikea. [image]Recently its extra-long-screw that used to be on the sides of the chair got loosened somehow. I tried to tight it by force but it is like super loose and it seems like there used to be something that holds the screw to the chair. How can I tighten it? The screw used is given below:
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This probably isn't on-topic here, but have you tried removing and then reinstalling the screws? What keeps the screws from going in any further?

Comment: Its super loose. The holes in the chair are bigger than the screw. The screws I have are the one that used to be in the place. Right now I wrap the screw in some paper and tights it but its temporary solution.

Comment: I can't begin to offer suggestions with what's given here. We'd need to see the assembly instructions or a parts diagram to know what we're dealing with.

Comment: I missed to add. This chair is not recently bought. The chair is there for more than 2 years.

Comment: I am looking for something that can be used to tighten the screw like something to wrap around the screw to make it tight.

Comment: The screw has a machine thread and should be screwing into a fastener of some type.   Is the tip of the screw damaged (broken)?  If so, it's not reaching the fastener.   Is there a similar screw mounted elsewhere in a similar/mirror-image position that you can experiment with?

Comment: @mike65535 the tip is intact but the screw is not fixing itself into the fastener. I don't have the fastener in place I guess.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the specifics of the fasteners used - could the fastener have a) fallen out  b) rotated in position to prevent the threads from lining up?  You could find a similar screw used elsewhere on the chair and remove it and try to compare everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a [Poang](https://www.ikea.com/rs/sr/assembly_instructions/poang-okvir-fotelje__AA-510890-5_pub.pdf).

The longer bolts (not screws) need a nut that has probably fallen out and got kicked under the sofa

[image: Poang assembly]

The shorter bolts, used at the top of the armrest, probably screw into a threaded insert.

[image: Poang assembly]

If this is problematic you can probably fit a [T-nut](https://www.screwfix.com/p/easyfix-4-pronged-tee-nut-m6-x-9mm-10-pack/79359) (likely to be a metric thread)

---

While you are fixing this, you should tighten up the other bolts (as Ikea advise you to do periodically) or apply some non-permanent [thread-lock fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-locking_fluid).

---

I have a couple of Poang disassembled in my garage, so I may be able to find out more later.

Comment: Thank You. This is exactly I was looking for. I think the object `123786` from the page #10 is missing. Is there any way I can buy those again?

Comment: @Arun: Your local Ikea probably have free help-yourself bins of these at the service/returns counter. If not, you can probably buy them at a local hardware store (take with you the bolt and the picture above)

Comment: Note: I think 123786 is just a locating pin/dowel. It won't hold a bolt in place. You may also need other parts that will fall out and get lost when bolts are removed (e.g. spacer 102319)